# Getting values from list<String> , split them and then slice them by parts, using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have List`<String>` from Spring MVC which i want to split, slice and print on browser. The problem is that i need to enter a start and end argument of slice() method as a variable from text-field. This is my code, but it doesn't work. Can someone helps me with that? This is my code:

```
    <body>
    <form>First value:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="firstvalue" />Last value:
        <br/>
        <input type="text" id="lastvalue" />
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Press</button>
        <p id="demos"></p>
    </form>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var str = "${first}";
            var arr = str.split(",");
            var first = document.getElementById('firstvalue');
            var second = document.getElementById('lastvalue');

            document.getElementById("demos").innerHTML = arr.slice('first', 'second');

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the result you wish to get with the string?

Comment: Numbers from 0 to 200.

Comment: Elaborate a bit please. What is the string you get, how should it look in the end and what does not work with your current provided code like it should?

Comment: The List<String> is numbers from 0 to 200. When i make the slice method, i need to get numbers, for example, from 3 to 20, but i want to enter start and end arguments  in the text-fields at the beginning. The function need to take them and then get me the result, but when i run the program and push the Press button, it gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

you got some issues in your code.

1. if `${first}` is `List<String>`, then you need to convert it to a concatenated single comma separated String. Because by `${first}` you are just printing list object.
2. slice expects index which is number, you are passing String
3. You are not doing .value after document.getElementById
4. You are not passing the user input variables first and second to slice, Instead you are passing hardcoded strings `'first'` and `'second'`.

Below is the fixed code

HTML

```
<form>First value:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="firstvalue" />Last value:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="lastvalue" />
    <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Press</button>
    <p id="demos"></p>
</form>
```

JS

```
var myFunction = function (e) { 

    var str = "${first}" // assuming this contains string like "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"; and not the List obect
    var arr = str.split(",");
    var first = document.getElementById('firstvalue').value;
    var second = document.getElementById('lastvalue').value;

    document.getElementById("demos").innerHTML = arr.slice(parseInt(first, 10),   parseInt(second, 10)).toString();
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's the same. It gives me nothing when i press the "Press" button.

Comment: @Veronica : There are few more issues in your code. Check the update in the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Now it' s working!  :))

Answer (score 0):

## What do we want to achieve?

We have two input textfields: one holding a start value and one holding an end value. On a click we want to create a range from the start to the end value and output it into a container.

### Solution

The solution is more simple than expected and we do not require split, slice and part. Also we do not really require a predefined list holding all values.

### Example

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function evalRange(){
                var tS = parseInt(document.querySelector('#inFrom').value); //Our start value;
                var tE = parseInt(document.querySelector('#inTo').value); //Our end value;
                var tR = document.querySelector('#demos'); //Our output div

                if (tE >= tS){
                    //We are using the Array.apply prototype to create a range
                    var tL = Array.apply(null, Array(tE - tS + 1)).map(function (a, i){return tS + i});

                    //We output the range into the demos div
                    tR.innerHTML = tL.join(',')
                }
                else tR.innerHTML = 'To has to be higher than from';

                //Returning the range list
                return tL
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type = 'text' id = 'inFrom' value = '10' />
        <input type = 'text' id = 'inTo' value = '20' />
        <b onclick = 'evalRange()'>Range</b>
        <div id = 'demos'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/91v3jg66/

Comment: Interesting and flexible.